# Configuration issue with ASP.Net MVC and Oracle on a Windows 10 Server (64-bit)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC application using Visual Studio 2013 Web Express with a backend database as Oracle 11g.  Everything works fine in development environment, i.e. with MVC App and Db deployed on a single machine.  I am able access and use this web app from a client machine and everything works just fine in development environment.  But when published and deployed on IIS 7 running on Windows 10 server, I am unable to establish the Oracle database connection.  I get an error called "Invalid user or logon failed".

I have installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013, which is available at following link,

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2013-2756823.html

The database driver that I am using is Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Dll, which is getting deployed on the App server (Windows 10 Server 64-bit).  I am bypassing the TNSNAMES.ORA file by specifying the long descriptor in the connection string.  Interestingly, I am able to access Oracle database on this Windows 10 server using Oracle SQL Developer.

It's to do with some configuration settings/Oracle server security settings or IIS settings, which prevents MVC application to pass thru'.

--Contents from Web.Config file

```
section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />
```

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.104)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=scott;Password=tiger;" />
```

--Code for OpenConnection() Method in OracleDatabaseHandler looks like this

```
    public class OracleDatabaseHandler
    {
        public OracleConnection objConn;
        private void OpenConnection()
        {
            //Load from App.Config file
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");  //Declaring Log4Net

            string sConnStr1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

            logger.Info("sConnString : " + sConnStr1);

            objConn = new OracleConnection();
            try
            {
                objConn.ConnectionString = sConnStr1;
                objConn.Open();
                if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    logger.Info("Connection opened successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info("Unable to open the connection");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.Message.ToString());
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
   }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is resolved. Here is what I did.**

The Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Dll did not work on client's Windows 10 Server machine (64-bit), because they didn't have this Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Dll over there. Our client refused to install Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013 on Windows 10 Server, which is right in way.

Then I removed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Dll from my ASP.NET MVC application and added Oracle.DataAccess.Dll instead. I downloaded the setup from this URL http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html and installed 64-bit ODAC 11.2 Release 6 (11.2.0.4.0) Xcopy for Windows x64. This is the best way to install ODAC components, you just need to read the readme.html very carefully and follow the instructions religiously.

In the ASP.NET MVC project, I added a reference to Oracle.DataAccess.Dll which was located in GAC (i.e. C:\Windows\Assembly). Changed the two parameters of this reference, namely, i) Copy Local to False and ii) Specific Version to False. After publishing the project, I observed that the Oracle.DataAccess.Dll was present in the application's bin folder. I deleted that DLL and then deployed the application on the client's Windows 10 Server (64-bit) machine. Since I had set the Specific Version to False, the application took the reference from GAC of Windows 10 Server and not the application's bin folder. Just to test my hypothesis, I deliberately copied the Oracle.DataAccess.Dll in the application's bin folder and saw my application failed. Deleting the Oracle.DataAccess.Dll from the application's bin folder forced application to look for the Oracle.DataAccess.Dll in GAC.

I also created a separate application pool so that it doesn't affect any existing (or even future) applications. I changed the application pool of my virtual directory with the one I created specifically for my application and it worked. Finally.